# $location partial path change

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

If there is s path of `/#/var1/oneVariable/var2/many,more,variables/var3/last,set` and I wanted to update the $location, is there a way to only update the variable part of the path without having to re-declare everything from the current path?

Is something like this possible?:

```
$location.path(var2 = 'changed,all,three';)
```

and having the result be `/#/var1/oneVariable/var2/changed,all,three/var3/last,set`

Comment: I dont think there is a method to do that, but you could always write your own by parsing your current location and then changing it based on the given input.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that it is possible by default. However, you can create a function by yourself that keeps track of the current variables and fills them in for you when you need to change one of them and calls `$location.path()`.

```
var currentParams = {
    var1: 'oneVariable',
    var2: 'many,more,variables',
    var3: 'last,set'
};
function changePath(params) {
    angular.forEach(params, function (value, key) {
        currentParams[key] = value;
    });
    $location.path('/var1/'+ currentParams.var1 + '/var2/' + currentParams.var2 + '/var3/' + currentParams.var3);
}
```

You can call it now by using `changePath({var2: 'changed,all,three'})`.
Note that this is a simplified example. You can make it more flexible and it would be good to put it into an Angular service.